# Exposing a serial USB device to a container

Tags: docker, docker-machine

What is the best way to expose a USB device (`/dev/cu.usbserial`) to a running Docker container? Is it possible to alias the device to a different name within the container similar to how port mapping works? I am trying to read and write to the serial device (flash firmware) from the container since I have all the tools within the container. I have outlined everything that I have tried so far below.

#### Trial 1: Using `--device`

Using the `--device` option, I receive the error: `docker: Error response from daemon: error gathering device information while adding custom device "/dev/cu.usbserial": no such file or directory`.

#### Trial 2: Using `--mount` & `--volume`

After adding the `/dev` path to File Sharing under preferences, I tried the following command:

```
docker run -it --rm --volume $(pwd):/home/app/ --volume /dev/cu.usbserial:/dev/cu.usbserial --entrypoint "/bin/bash" container:tag
```

But this command actually just hangs forever. And using the `--mount` analog below:

```
docker run -it --rm --volume $(pwd):/home/app/ --mount type=bind,source=/dev/cu.usbserial,target=/dev/cu.usbserial --entrypoint "/bin/bash" container:tag
```

I receive the following error: `Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /dev/cu.usbserial`.

#### Trial 3: Using symlink

I also tried to symlink the device to the directory that I attach to the container, but the container is not able to follow the link.

### Edit (29/6/2020)

As @Peaceful James points out, if your host machine runs OSX, there is no current solution to this problem. The issue is being tracked [here](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/900).

Comment: I actually did this exact thing for a professional project a few years ago.  I will find the project and see what my dockerfile looked like. Hopefully docker hasn't changed too much since then.

Comment: @PeacefulJames That would be great, I've been trying to figure this out for a while.

Comment: I see that I was running the container in "privileged" mode:
```
sudo docker run -t --name my_data_logger --restart=always --privileged my_docker_repo/my_data_logger:0.0.1
```
That's my exact command (with actual production names change slightly).

Answer (score 2):

Try running your docker container in privileged mode:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm --volume $(pwd):/home/app/ --privileged --entrypoint "/bin/bash" container:tag
```

See here for details: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities

NB: this won't work on "Docker for Mac". See here: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/900

Comment: When trying with `--mount`, I receive `invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /dev/cu.usbserial` and with `--volume`, I receive `Mounts denied: EOF. ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled`.

Comment: You don't need to do the `--mount`. The exact command I gave works for me - I can see the host's `/dev` folder on the container. Did you try the exact command I gave? Which directory are you running it from? That `$(pwd)` means you have to be in the correct directory.

Comment: I see what you mean; my host machine runs OSX, and the device I am looking for is `/dev/cu.usbserial-AL00EW7M` or `/dev/tty.usbserial-AL00EW7M`. After running the container with your command, I can see a number of new files in the `/dev/` directory in the container, but none with the names I am looking for. Perhaps the name changes during the mapping, I don't know.

Comment: OK I think things are different using "docker for Mac". I assumed you were on Linux. There is an issue for this exact problem with docker on macs: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/900  ....  It seems like what you are trying to do cannot be done with a Mac. Do you have access to a Linux machine you can use instead?

Comment: Wow, an issue from 2016. Thanks for the link; it seems like there is no real solution yet though.

Comment: Yes, sorry I cannot help any more than this. I hope you can find a Linux machine for coding. Good luck, fellow coder!

Comment: Thanks for the help; I'll figure something out in the future and add edits to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Run in privileged mode without the volume mount. Privileged mode will give the container visibility to /dev without any extra mounts.

```
sudo docker run -it --rm --privileged --entrypoint "/bin/bash" container:tag
```

Comment: This only works if your host machine is running Linux; see my edit.